# Why has my R devtools package load failed?

Tags: r, devtools

I am trying to create my first package using the instructions on the hadley devtools wiki. I am using Windows 7 Professional, I have loaded R-tools 3.1, and I am using R 3.0.2. I get the error below when I run the has_devel() command and I do no know why. Does anyone know how I can successfully install devtools given the error below.

```
has_devel()
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.2/bin/x64/R" --vanilla CMD SHLIB foo.c 

Error: Command failed (1)
> traceback()
6: stop("Command failed (", status, ")", call. = FALSE)
5: system_check(r_path, options, c(r_env_vars(), env_vars), ...)
4: force(code)
3: in_dir(path, system_check(r_path, options, c(r_env_vars(), env_vars), 
   ...))
2: R("CMD SHLIB foo.c", tempdir())
1: has_devel()
```

There is an existing related question, except in that example R is run on MAC OSX ([The check for successful devtools load (has_devel) fails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17752962/2863091)).

Comment: RStudio provides great support fro writing packages, are you using it? It's integrated with devtools.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The check for successful devtools load (has\_devel) fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752962/the-check-for-successful-devtools-load-has-devel-fails)

Comment: The question you link to provides the answer to your question. Install make. Or don't use devtools.

Comment: @Fernando I am using RStudio yes, the integration with devtools was part of the reason I chose to use it.

Comment: @Thomas I have installed make, but the error remains. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

My Rtools installation was not complete.

I re-installed the most recent version of Rtools from CRAN (http://cran.rstudio.com/). I re-installed devtools using the instructions supplied by Hadley Wickham (http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Philosophy.html) and the error was fixed, has_devel() returned TRUE.

```
 has_devel()
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.2/bin/x64/R" --vanilla CMD SHLIB foo.c 

gcc -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c foo.c -o foo.o
gcc -m64 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o foo.dll tmp.def foo.o -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib/x64 -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.2/bin/x64 -lR
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

see here for the same issue https://github.com/hadley/devtools/issues/234
(solution provided  by hadley, running the script in this gist https://gist.github.com/hadley/4506250)

Answer (score 0):

I have installed first time to a directory C:\Apps\Rtools without checking the environmental variable add step during installation. But, I have manually added the path into the PATH variable. Then, I had the same problem.

Then I reinstalled to the default directory C:\Rtools and this time I checked the environmental variable add step during installation. Then it worked.

Comment: can you add more information about operation system? and R version?